# Can three related lists be deleted and recreated from template(with content) with the same name and still be related?

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, office-365

Office 365 SharePoint 2013 
PROBLEM: A corrupted list(A) that does not allow create, edit, or delete.  It has two related lists (B&C).  Cannot delete and restore A because it is related to B&C.

WHAT I'M THINKING: Create Templates of A, B, & C (with content) then remove relationships and then delete all three lists.  Create new lists with the same names from the templates.

QUESTIONS:  Will this work? Will the relationships restore?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem and the short answer: No! BUT!!!
I tested it like this.. Made two lists

- ListA
- ListB

made a cascading lookup from ListB to ListA created a couple of items in both lists and created templates with content of them. Deleted the lists and recreated them.. the items where there, but the relationship was missing, so the columns where empty, and the lookup didnt work.

Thats what I read from your question?!

Then I downloaded ListB.stp and edited the manifest.xml inside. Found my lookupfield and edited the List attribute from the GUID that pointed to the original list to the urlname Lists/ListA

Uploaded the file and created the list - and boom it worked.

Comment: Excellent! You did read the question correctly. I tested the same by recreating the lists and came up with the same results.  I will try your solution! Thank you!